# ts The property 'formBuilder' is declared but its value is never read

Tags: angular, typescript, formbuilder, tslint, tsconfig

I used the following properties in my tsconfig.json file as complierOptions :

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true
  },
```

I can see the unused variables underlined in my Visual Studio Code, and I can delete them, except for one variable that is used but it shows me the following message :

```
[ts] The property 'formBuilder' is declared but its value is never read.
```

I declared it like this :

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){
this.form = formBuilder.group({myFormControl: new FormControl()});
}
```

Comment: Is the issue on this line, or is it in another file ?

Comment: @trichetriche the issue is in the injection of formBuilder it declares it as an unused variable which is not the case

Comment: use `this.formBuilder.group`

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka using it as this.formBuilder.group with private modifier or removing the private modifier and using it directly work, both methods work, thank you guys :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `private` modifier in the constructor parameters from front of the `formBuilder` or use via `this` - `this.formBuilder.group`.

Modifier in the constructor parameter just creates a property on the component. Your code is equivalent to this

```
private formBuilder: FormBuilder;

constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
   this.formBuilder = formBuilder;
   this.form = formBuilder.group({myFormControl: new FormControl()});
}
```

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka comment is a better solution, because it requires less code.